# Tokenise lines with quoted elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I need to tokenise strings in Ruby - string.split is almost perfect, except some of the strings may be enclosed in double-quotes, and within them, whitespace should be preserved. In the absence of lex  for Ruby (correct?), writing a character-by-character tokenizer seems silly. What are my options?

I want a loop that's essentially:

```
while !file.eof:
    line = file.readline
    tokens = line.tokenize() # like split() but handles "some thing" as one token
end
```

I.e an an array of white-space delimited fields, but with correct handling of quoted sequences. Note there is no escape sequence for the quotes I need to handle.

The best I can imagine so far, is repeatedly match()ing a reg-exa which matches either the quotes sequence or everything until the next whitespace character, but even then I'm not sure how to formulate than neatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Andrew said the most straightforward way is parse input with stock CSV library and set appropriate `:col_sep` and `:quote_char` options.
If you insist to parse manually you may use the following pattern in a more ruby way:

```
file.each do |line|
    tokens = line.scan(/\s*("[^"]+")|(\w+)/).flatten.compact
    # do whatever with array of tokens
end
```

Answer (score 0):

split accepts a regex so you could just write the regexp you want and call split on the line you just read.

`line.split(/\w+/)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ruby's [CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), and [use](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) a space (`" "`) as the `:col_sep`

> :col_sep
>
> The String placed between each field. This String will be transcoded
>   into the data’s Encoding before parsing.